# Google Apps Script - Using Sidebar form to append a row to spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

This script should append a new row to my spreadsheet 'onclick' of the button, however it doesn't.  Ultimately I want to be able to add data to each textbox corresponding to a column and append a new row.  Not sure why this doesn't work.  How do I append a new row?  THis script works in the script editor when I run it, just not in the sidebar html.

```js
    // Use this code for Google Docs, Forms, or new Sheets.
    function onOpen() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('SideBar')
      .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
      
      .addToUi();
  
    }

    function openDialog() {
     var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index");
     html.setTitle('Gmf Sent Msg Form'); 
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
  
    }

   function insertRow(){
    var doc =     SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RY3TZvU-        TFhlCyF9TKRk4Hb4b6Q1TnYa5K7ixyktykY/edit#gid=0");
     doc.getActiveSheet().appendRow(['700','9/12/16','PO 16-45789'])
  
  
    }
```

```html
<body>
Use this form to enter information into the cells of the spreadsheet.<br>
<form>
<p>ID</p>
<input type="text" name="txtID" />
<p>Date</p>
<input type="text" name="txtDate"/>
<p>Subject</p>
<input type="text" name="txtSub" />
<input type="button" value="Append Row" onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(insertRow)" />
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At this line:**

```
<input type="button" value="Append Row" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(insertRow)" />
```

You're setting the callback function [withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) but you're not calling any server-side function, to call it directly you need to use:

```
google.script.run.insertRow();
```

If you want to set the callback function to run if the server-side function returns successfully.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).insertRow();
```

For more information, see the guide of [communicating with server functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) and [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#top_of_page).

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I know I tried that but I must of missed something.  Either way you helped to understand it better.  I have less than 15 points so I can't upvote your answer, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, happy to help (: