# Can I append/push values of html elements to each row of an array generated from a html table within the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-sheets

I'm doing a html form for online requests by users. The form has text input fields for user contact details (e.g. user name, department, email, etc) at the top, followed by a table with multiple rows for different items requested.

I want to have the form data appended into Google Sheets, where each table row (item requested) is appended as a separate row in Sheets, with the user contact details added to each row, i.e. the contact details have to repeat for the same user.
[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LvPMNf1i7gBcGj0r5hj1WkdXDaO3JQJr_YUCwHJbA_c/edit?usp=sharing)

Tried Google Forms -- it's good for single item requests -- one Google Form for one item. But for multiple item requests by the same user, the user has to key in contact details repeatedly. Branching to repeat sections in Forms didn't work, since additional items are added as new columns and not as a new row. Thus I tried a rudimentary html form.

[FormTableDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD3P6.png)

Code.gs:

```
function addRows(valuesAll) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,valuesAll.length,valuesAll[0].length).setValues(valuesAll);
}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?!= include('CSS_Table'); ?>    
  </head>
  <body>
  Name: <input type="text" id="Name"><br>
  Phone: <input type="text" id="Phone"><br>
  Email: <input type="email" id="Email"><br>
  Department: <input type="text" id="Dept"><br>

    <table id="tableRows">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="inputCell" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttonBar">
      <input class="inputButton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
      <input class="inputButton" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
    </div>
    <?!= include('JS_Table'); ?>    
  </body>
```

JS_Table.html:

```
<script>
  function buttonClick(button) {
    if( button.value === "Submit" ) {
      var values = [];
      var table = document.getElementById("tableRows");
      for( var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++ ) {
        values.push([]);
        var row = table.rows[i];
        for( var j=0; j<row.cells.length; j++ ) {
          var cell = row.cells[j].firstChild.value;
          values[i-1].push(cell)

       var user = ["Name","Phone","Email","Dept"];
       var valuesAll =  values.concat(user)
        }
      }
      google.script.run.addRows(valuesAll);
      google.script.host.close();
    }
    else {
      if( confirm("Exit without saving?") ) google.script.host.close();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Tried to simply concat the id's of the user details, with the table array. But the google script didn't work. Appreciate any suggestions for this newbie.

The Execution Transcript:

```
[19-05-25 19:42:15:580 PDT] Starting execution 
[19-05-25 19:42:15:587 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds
[19-05-25 19:42:15:672 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sheet1]) [0.084 seconds] 
[19-05-25 19:42:15:772 PDT] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.099 seconds] 
[19-05-25 19:42:15:772 PDT] Sheet.getRange([2, 1, 9, 4]) [0 seconds] 
[19-05-25 19:42:15:779 PDT] Execution failed: Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 17, file "Code") [0.189 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: "_But the google script didn't work._" Would you be more specific? Did the script run but not meet your expectations; did the script not run at all; if the script failed, then please share the Execution transcript. You might also share your spreadsheet, or a version thereof, so we can see what the output looks like. You might benefit from reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you read [Google Apps Script - Using Sidebar form to append a row to spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460517/).

Comment: Tedinoz, I've put images of my sheet, and the form dialog. Also thanks for pointing me to Execution transcript. I've corrected a bug due to that. I've shared the latest transcript, the error is clearly in the arraying attempt. No data was added to the Sheet.

Comment: I don't think the Sidebar form would work for my use case, as a single user can request for multiple line items. It comes back to needing repetitive inputs as the Google Form.

Comment: Please provide all the code for the html form, not just the script.

Comment: Regarding sidebar or not sidebar; I think it is irrelevant. So long as you html and javascript is running properly - then "where" you put the code shouldn't matter. I'm certainly testing in a sidebar.

Comment: BTW, a spreadsheet image is NOT very helpful. The actual spreadsheet is always far more desirable. You are putting the onus back onto the people trying to help to develop a spreadsheet, populate the script editor and so on. In the scheme of things, it is time investment that makes it less attractive to help. That's why sharing your spreadsheet (or a version thereof) is to your own advantage.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question; I'm still learning my way. I've put in the html code and a link to the Sheet. Thank you again for your feedback.

Comment: Try my revised answer. You're not collecting the name details, plus you're not converting your data from an array to a two dimensional object suited to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the OPs code.
1 - output is not adjusted for Google's two-dimensional range.
2 - the Name, phone, email and department are not collected.

The following answer is written to work in the sidebar (not essential) and also tests whether the form data is complete - that is: whether there is complete data for  the Item, Description, Quantity and Location in each row . The OP can easily remove this test.

**56302393_04_gs.gs**

---

```
function showSidebar04() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("56302393_04_html");
  htmlOutput.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setTitle("56302393_04 Form");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}

function addRows04(valuesAll) {  
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: valuesall = "+valuesAll);
  var testdata = [];
  var testdata = valuesAll.slice(0);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: testdata = "+testdata);

  // remove the name fields
  testdata.splice(0, 4);
  // get the number of fields 
  var testdatalength = (testdata.length);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: testdata length = "+testdatalength);
  // get the number of empty fields - were looking for rows that are inclonplete
  var newempties = testdatalength - testdata.filter(String).length;
  var adjustedlength = testdatalength-newempties;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: newempties = "+newempties+", so adjusted length = "+adjustedlength);

  // calculate the number of rows
  var netrows = adjustedlength/4;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: adjusted length divided by 4 = "+netrows);
  // is the result an integers - get the mod
  var netrowMod = adjustedlength % 4;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: residual = "+netrowMod);
  // test whether newrows is an integer by testing whether mode = 0
  if(netrowMod !== 0){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: netrows: "+netrows+" is not an integer");
    Browser.msgBox("The data rows were not completed evenly. Code aborted");
    return;
  }

  // setup the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // get the name data
  var name = valuesAll[0];
  var phone = valuesAll[1];
  var email = valuesAll[2];
  var dept = valuesAll[3];

  // set the range
  var outputRange = sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,1,netrows,8);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG Output range = "+range.getA1Notation());

  var datastart = 4;
  var alldata = [];

  for (var i = 0; i<netrows;i++){
    var datarow = []; 

    // get the row information
    var item = valuesAll[(i*datastart)+4];
    var desc = valuesAll[(i*datastart)+5]
    var qty = valuesAll[(i*datastart)+6];
    var locn = valuesAll[(i*datastart)+7];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", values = "+item+" "+desc+" "+qty+" "+locn);
    // build the row fields
    datarow.push(item);
    datarow.push(desc);
    datarow.push(qty);
    datarow.push(locn);
    datarow.push(name);
    datarow.push(phone);
    datarow.push(email);
    datarow.push(dept);

    // accumulate the rows 
    alldata.push(datarow);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: datarow = "+datarow)
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: alldata = "+alldata)
  }
  // update the values of the outputrange
  outputRange.setValues(alldata);
}
```

---

**56302393_04_html.html**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table id="tableName">
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="name" value="Fred"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Phone: </td><td><input type="text" name="phone" value="0412987654"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="email" name="email" value="fred@example.com"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Department: </td><td><input type="text" name="dept" value="Sydney"></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
<style>
  .inputCell { float: right; width: 40%; }
  .inputCell { float: left; width: 80%; }
  .inputButton { float: left; width: 50%; }
</style>
    <table id="tableRows">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="1"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="amd"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="11"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="B12"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="2"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="ibm"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="22"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="Z23"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="3"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="digital"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="33"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="A49"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="4"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="apple"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="44"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="K12"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="5"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="rex"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="55"></td>
       <td><input class="inputCell" type="text" value="ascot"></td>
     </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="buttonBar">
      <input class="inputButton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
      <input class="inputButton" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
    </div>
<script>
  function buttonClick(button) {
    if( button.value === "Submit" ) {

      var valuesAll = [];

      // Collect name details
      var tablename = document.getElementById("tableName");
      var myname = tablename.rows[0].cells[1].children[0].value
      var myphone = tablename.rows[1].cells[1].children[0].value
      var myemail = tablename.rows[2].cells[1].children[0].value
      var mydept = tablename.rows[3].cells[1].children[0].value

      valuesAll.push(myname);
      valuesAll.push(myphone);
      valuesAll.push(myemail);
      valuesAll.push(mydept);


      // collect row details
      var table = document.getElementById("tableRows");

      for( var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++ ) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        for( var j=0; j<row.cells.length; j++ ) {
          var cell = row.cells[j].firstChild.value;
          valuesAll.push(cell);
        }
      }
      google.script.run.addRows04(valuesAll);
      google.script.host.close();
    }
    else {
      if( confirm("Exit without saving?") ) google.script.host.close();
    }
  }
</script> 
  </body>
```

---

**Output screenshot**
[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much. It has worked in my preliminary tests. Appreciate the extra test feature that was put in and all detailed comments made -- very helpful for learning!